# Is "to share or to have a common interest" a tautology?

Tags: synonyms

I often read and hear "to share a common .." but it seems very pleonastic to me. Isn't it saying the same thing twice? In other words, is it a tautology, and if so, should it be avoided or is it acceptable, even in a scholarly context?

Answer (score 1):

A [TAUTOLOGY](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tautology) is a needless repetition of an idea, statement, or word.

One can have common interests that are not shared. One can share common platforms, common living spaces, and many other things. One can also share uncommon interests

[Share](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+%22share%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a): a part or portion of a larger amount that is divided among a number of people, or to which a number of people contribute. Synonyms include portion, part, division, quota, quantum, allowance, ration, allocation, measure, due. One can portion money, space, etc.

> [HPRLCL](http://www.hprlcl.com/) is a location-based social discovery platform that allows travelers, locals and everyone in between to discover and share uncommon urban experiences.

[Examples of tautologies](http://grammar.about.com/od/tz/g/tautolterm.htm) include

> A *major* *nuclear disaster* could have been sparked off...
>   ...who *died* of a *fatal dose* of heroin.
>   ...*equalized* the game to a *2-2 draw*
>   ...*kept it* from his friends that he was a *secret* drinker

Comment: While using `share` and `common` as `use amongst several people` and `something shared by several people`, I fail to see how one could share uncommon interests. Of course, if I tell you something, I can say I "share" something with you, and people might be "sharing" information about interests they do not have in common. That is a completely different meaning (I think) than what the OP refers to. The same goes for sharing uncommon interests: if we are both interested in the possible use of declension in dolphin mating calls, we would share an interest, but it is an uncommon one.

Answer (score 1):

At first sight, this does look like a tautology, and you might think that sharing something means that it is common to the sharers anyway. But what else can you do with something that is common? These expressions seem rather more like reinforcements than redundancies.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, in the meaning in which the phrase is usually understood, `to share a common interest` is indeed a tautology because it means that some people both have an interest in something that they both are interested in: both `share` and `common` indicate that the object is applicable to all subjects involved.

In that case I would indeed say

> They share an interest.

or

> They have a common interest.

On the other hand, if I invite individual in a group to share some of their personal details with the group, they are certainly invited to list their interests or hobbies. If those interests are not applicable to others in the group, or if those interests are out of the ordinary in general (see my example in my comment to Susan), it would be correct to say they are sharing uncommon interests. 
If their interests *do* apply to the rest of the group as well, one could similarly state (without it being a tautology) that they are sharing common interests.

This would involve a different meaning of the verb `to share` altogether, though.

In the same way, if we want to express how common (or *usual*) interests are that two or more individuals share, the statement

> They share a common interest.

Could be read as "they are both interested in something that is very common, like pop music." In that case, there is also no tautology.

TLDR:

So, if "share" means "to tell something" or "common" is understood to mean "usual", there is no tautology. In the general sense of "they share an interest" meaning "they have a common interest", I would see "they share a common interest" as a tautology.

Comment: But it's only as 'wrong' as _spic and span_, _odds and ends_, _nook and cranny_ . . .,